# How does one set a variable in a command using Mediatr with Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, mediatr

I have a simple functional style test for output of a command that I've written using Mediatr's `IRequest` and `IRequestHandler<>`

```
[Fact]
public void TestReturnValuesAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var handler = new Mock<IRequestHandler<SyncSubmerchantDataCommand, CommandResult<int>>>();
    handler.Setup(x => x.Handle(It.IsAny<SyncSubmerchantDataCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(new CommandResult<int>(0, ResultStatus.Success, "string"));

    // Act
    var result = handler.Object.Handle(new SyncSubmerchantDataCommand(), new CancellationToken());

    // Assert
    result.Result.Data.ShouldBe(0);
    result.Result.Status.ShouldBe(ResultStatus.Success);
    result.Result.Message.ShouldBe("string");
}
```

Since this command runs as a background task, I don't want it interrupted. I have a variable, `submerchantList`, that is of type `List<T>` which is used in a `foreach` loop to do work. The work is set in a try-catch because I don't want the command interrupted, as I stated before. I want to test the output of the what is written to my logs (_log.info) if an exception is thrown during this process.

```
public class CommandNameHandler : IRequestHandler<source, destination> {
    // constructors and privates
    public async destination Handle(param, token)
    {
        var submerchantList = db call.ToList();
        foreach (var item in submerchantList)
        {
            try {
                //does work
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
               if (item != null)
                   _log.info($"{e} - {item.Id}");
            }
            return some out put
        }
```

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set the value of the any variable, such as the `submerchantList` within the `Handle` in order to throw the exception for my next test. I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION:

Here was the solution: Stubbing the database call by injecting an in-memory DbSet. I used this resource learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/… This issue was `db call.ToList` It looked something like this `_db.Table.Include(x => x.Foreign).Where(x => x.Foreign.Field == Enum.Value).ToListAsync()` While I was setting up the Mock DbSet, I had to use the string version, not the LINQ-chain version in the unit test. So, that means `mockDbset.Setup(x => x.Table.Include("Foreign")).Returns(myCustomDbSet);` Hope that helps someone!

Comment: You can stub `"db call".ToList()`

Comment: @mxmissile That's what I'd like to do, but I'm having trouble accessing it, whether I mock the command or new it up, the only option it seems I have is to setup the handle, but nothing within the handle.

Comment: Inject your db in the handler's constructor. Stub the "call".

Comment: @mxmissile if I understand this correctly you're saying:

`var db = new Mock<dbContext>();`
`db.Setup(x => x.Entity).Returns(new Entity { //data});`
`await CommandHandler(db.Object);`

right? Sorry running slow this morning.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mxmissile/4df25560a2643d6a52702a3206675233

Comment: Oh I see now. I'll have to refactor for an interface for my dbcontext.

Comment: Still no success on this. I can sucessfully mock a dbset and inject that into the passed handler for my db context. the problem I have now is in my command query. The command returns null for any data returned with an .Include(x => x.Whatever) in the linq query.

Comment: Here was the solution:

Stubbing the database call by injecting an in-memory DbSet. I used this resource

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#testing-query-scenarios

This issue was 'db call.ToList' It looked something like this 
`_db.Table.Include(x => x.Foreign).Where(x => x.Foreign.Field == Enum.Value).ToListAsync()`

While I was setting up the Mock DbSet, I had to use the string version, not the LINQ version in the unit test. So, that means

`mockDbset.Setup(x => x.Table.Include("Foreign")).Returns(myCustomDbSet);`

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: @CSharpMinor you should actually add [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041530/how-does-one-set-a-variable-in-a-command-using-mediatr-with-moq#comment95023754_54041530) as a self answer to you question. Others would find it easier if it was an answer rather than in the comments.